# Why setstate error is coming even after defining it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

In my code i am trying to get value from nodejs and trying to show in react. My image's format is in base64. I then tried to setstate but it gives me error named setstate is undefined. My setstate is image. Can anyone please tell what's the error?
Fileupload.js:

```
const getImage = () => {
    console.log('getImage');
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/showallimages`).then((result) => {
        this.setState({image: result});
        console.log(result);
    });
}
getImage();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          uploadImage(e);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={saveImage}>Save</button>
      <br/>
</div>
  );
}

export default File;
```

Server.js:

```
app.get('/api/showallimages',(req,res)=>{
    mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM imagetb',(err,rows,fields)=>{
    if(!err)
    res.send(rows);
    else
        console.log(err);
})
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Server Running On 3000");
});
```

Edit, Here's is the code that wasn't added it is part of Fileupload.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from 'axios';

function File() {
  // const [baseImage, setBaseImage] = useState("");
const [image] = useState("");
  const uploadImage = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const base64 = await convertBase64(file);
    window.bs64=base64;
    saveImage();
    //setBaseImage(base64);
  };

  const convertBase64 = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      };

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  };

const saveImage = () => {
  axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/image",{
    imgName: window.bs64,
  });
};

const getImage = () => {
    console.log('getImage');
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/showallimages`).then((result) => {
        this.setState({image: result});
        console.log(result);
    });
}
getImage();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          uploadImage(e);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={saveImage}>Save</button>
      <br/>
</div>
  );
}

export default File;
```

Comment: It looks like you might be using a function component. `this.setState` is only available on class components. Please see the React docs on [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), specifically the [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook.

Comment: So how can i put it in class as i have my other objects that are not in code?

Comment: You're also probably going to encounter an infinite loop since you're calling `getImage` from within the body of the function. So after you fix this error regarding state, you will want to read about [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) so that it only calls it once.

Comment: Can you please help by answering as i am too new to react.

Comment: function File() {
  // const [baseImage, setBaseImage] = useState("");
const [image] = useState("");
  const uploadImage = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const base64 = await convertBase64(file);
    window.bs64=base64;
    saveImage();
    //setBaseImage(base64);
  };

  const convertBase64 = (file) => {return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{constfileReader = new FileReader();fileReader.readAsDataURL(file); fileReader.onload =() => {resolve(fileReader.result);};

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  };

Comment: This was the code that i didn't include

Comment: I made a function

Comment: Ps: the code was minimized

Comment: Don't put code blocks in comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68179475/edit) your question to add more context.

Comment: Okay, I will edit to question

Comment: I really think the most helpful thing for you will be to go through the linked documentation and try to understand it. It looks like your issue is here `const [image] = useState("");`. You aren't getting the updater function. Could be as simple as `const [image, setImage] = useState("");` and then use `setImage` instead of `this.setState`.

Comment: It says Line 40:  'setState' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: setState({image: result}); This was done according you said

Comment: `const [image] = useState("");` > `const [image, setImage] = useState("");`
`this.setState({image: result});` > `setImage(result)`

Comment: That is not what I said... Please read the docs. I can help you fix this, but if you don't understand why then it's not going to help long-term... `setImage`, and `setImage(result)`.

Comment: Yes this actually helped me but it is sending infinite requests

Comment: When actually i just want it to send one request

Comment: @letter Please read my second comment.

Comment: So how can i fix this infinite thing?

Comment: Look into the useEffect hook with an empty array as a dependancy.

Comment: Can you tell what can be the code @kennedydmb

Comment: @Letter Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. We have given you plenty of resources in order to be able to solve your problem. Please make an attempt, and then if you get stuck, research it, and if you're still stuck - post a new question with the steps you took and where its not working.

Comment: Yes i made a try to do it but still it gives me error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function

Answer (score 1):

**For class based approach**

```
import React from 'react';
        import axios from 'axios'
        
        class File {
        
           constructor(){
             this.state = {
                image: '',
                text: ''
             }
            this.getImage = this.getImage.bind(this) // Not needed if you use arrow function
           }
        
          componentDidMount(){
             this.getImage();
          }
        
          getImage(){
            axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/showallimages`).then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                this.setState({image: result});
            });
           }

    
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <button>Save</button>
            </div>
          );
      }
            
    }
            
     export default File;
```

****And your functional way****

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from 'axios';

function File() {
 
const [state, setState] = useState("");

 const getImage = () => {
        console.log('getImage');
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/showallimages`).then((result) => {
            setState({image: result});  //setState defined above as updater
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
 
useEffect(()=>{
   getImage();
},[])




  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button>Save</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default File
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is only available for class component, where as functional components make use of `useState` hook. Either use, `useState` or make your component as class.

```js
import React from 'react'

export default class App extends React.Component {
   
   constructor(props){
       super(props)
       this.state = {
           image: ''
       }
   }

   getImage = () => {
axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/showallimages`).then((result) => {
           this.setState({image: result});
       });
   }
   
   uploadImage = (e) => {
    //Your code
   }
   
   saveImage = (e) => {
    //Your code
   }
   
   render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.uploadImage(e);
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={this.saveImage}>Save</button>
          <br/>
        </div>
      )
   }
   
   componentDidMount(){
      this.getImage();
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you seem to have posted incomplete code, but if the question is why "this.setState" is undefined then that is because you're mixing up functional components and class-based components.

This is a functional component where you use useState if you want the component to have any local state. useState returns a tuple of a getter and a setter. You can only manipulate the state via the setter - setGreeting in this case.

```
const Greeter = (props) => {
    const [greeting, setGreeting] = useState("Hello")

    const updateGreeting = () => {
        setGreeting("Bye");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{ greeting }</div>
            <button click={updateGreeting}></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is a class-based component. Class-based components do have a this reference since they're regular JavaScript classes. They do have a property state and a corresponding setter-method setState.

```
class Greeter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { greeting: "Hello" };
    }

    updateGreeting(){
        this.setState({ greeting: "Bye" };
    }
    

    render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <div>{ this.state.greeting }</div>
               <button click={updateGreeting}>Update greeting</button>
           </div>
       )
    }
}
```

You can mix and match class-based and functional components. I for one find the functional components much more elegant to read and write. Check out the introductory talk at React Conf to get an easier introduction to hooks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpw9EHDh2bM

Answer (score 0):

`const [image] = useState("");` becomes `const [image, setImage] = useState("");`
`this.setState({image: result});` becomes `setImage(result)`

Switch this:

```
const getImage = () => {
    console.log('getImage');
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/showallimages`).then((result) => {
        this.setState({image: result});
        console.log(result);
    });
}
getImage();
```

To this (don't forget to import useEffect just like useState)

```
useEffect(()=>{
axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/api/showallimages`).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        setImage(result)
    });
},[])
```

I would strongly suggest that you look into how the useEffect hook works. The empty array here just means that this will run on the first render of the component.

Comment: This code is almost right but i want to make request without button click

Comment: Like at starting when body starts

Comment: I also did like this before with empty brackets but it doesn't send automatic request

Comment: If this code resolves your error in your original question, then the question is resolved. Anything further is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I also asked in comments how to prints this so atleast tell me that so that my question can be solved

Comment: Plus just to tell your code doesn't send showallimages request

Comment: Which was the major issue